# Wordpress Custom Post Loop can't exclude category

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to exclude a category from a custom post type loop but with no luck. I have no idea why this isn't working. I have looked all over the internet but no luck, please can someone help identify the issue.

I have a category with an ID of 141.

[image]

I am running through a loop of posts where I am trying to exclude posts assigned to that category but they are still showing up in the loop. Where am I going wrong? Here is my code.

```
<?php 
     
                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'programme',
                'cat' => -141,
                );


      
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 

     
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
          ?>

                <div class="grid-item">  
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                </div>

                <?php 
 
            endwhile; 
        else: 
        
            _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' ); 
        endif; 

        wp_reset_postdata(); 
        ?>
```

Comment: Change `'cat' => '-141',` instead of  `'cat' => -141,` in your `$args`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar issue, I managed to fix it by using this code instead.

```
$args = array(
                'post_per_page' => '-1',
                    'post_type' => 'programme',
                'tax_query' => array(
                   array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'ticket-category',
                   'field' => 'slug',
                   'terms' => array( 'savers-tickets' ),
                   'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                   )
                   ),
                );
```